# Laravel contains relation of relation

Tags: php, laravel, relation

I have the relations

```
Trainee->hasMany->Poke
Company->hasMany->Poke

Poke->belongsTo->Trainee
Poke->belongsTo->Company
```

Now, I want to check if a `Trainee` contains a `Poke` from a `Company`. How can I do this the cleanest? I would prefer something like `$trainee->containsPokeFrom($company);` because I am using this in my blade file, but if thats not an option, than it's ok.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would use the `exists()` method on your `pokes` relationship method:

```php
class Trainee extends Model
{
    public function pokes()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Poke::class);
    }

    public function containsPokeFrom(Company $company)
    {
        return $this->pokes()->where(function ($poke) use ($company) {
            $poke->where('company_id', $company->getKey());
        })->exists();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, you are a genius!

Comment: @KuebelElch15 Thanks. Not a genius, just someone who’s worked with Laravel a fair bit :)

Comment: @MartinBean Can you explain why `where()` with `closure` is needed here?

Comment: @IndianCoding To restrict the pokes to the specified company only. Otherwise it’ll return the trainee’s pokes from _every_ company.

Answer (score 0):

You can get data with `with()` method.

Example:

```
public function getTrainee()
{
    return Trainee::with('Poke.Company')->get();
    // Here you will find all trainee which associated with multiple pokes which belongs to a company
}
```

Comment: I want to check if a specific trainee contains a relation with a poke from a specific company. Like `Trainee A has a Poke from Company B`. Or `has Company A already made a Poke to Trainee B`?